# How to prevent iPhone users upload more than one image

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, plupload

I'm building an app using html5/css/js that users can upload images on a div. On android is working fine, the user click on a link and he can select an image to upload. But when I select an image from iPhone, the user can select more than one image. How can I make iPhone users select only one image?

I'm using plupload plugin, here's the js:

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        browse_button: 'browse', // this can be an id of a DOM element or the DOM element itself
        url: 'upload.php',
        unique_names: true,
        filters: [{
            title: "Img type valid",
            extensions: "jpg"
        }],
        init: callbacks
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ramon, you can do it using `multi_selection = false`.

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    browse_button: 'browse', // this can be an id of a DOM element or the DOM element itself
    url: 'upload.php',
    unique_names: true,
    multi_selection: false,
    filters: [{
        title: "Img type valid",
        extensions: "jpg"
    }],
    init: callbacks
});
```